# Error 400 when trying to Connect Azure Function App to Azure Cosmos DB Table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I am trying to connect to azure CosmosDB Table from function app.

I am getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

When trying to perform the same connection from the sample c# project in visual studio, it works fine.

Code Snippet:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString;           
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(connectionString);

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("People");

table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The connection string is:

> DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=digital-signature-db;AccountKey=XXX==;TableEndpoint=https://digital-signature-db.documents.azure.com

Full error stack:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.SignPDF
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.SignPDF ---> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. ---> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.GetTaskResult(Task task) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 453
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.<>c.b__26_0(Task t) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 276
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>      at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 276
>      at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionInvokerBase.cs : 90
>      at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
>      at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
>      at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
>      at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Ex…

Please Advice.

Comment: Do you connect locally the same database?

Comment: Looks like this is an issue only in functions portal. Just tried a sample in azure functions using timer trigger to connect to cosmos db which uses Table API.

Comment: @Mikhail - Yes, I am connection to the exact same database. That why it's weird and looks like app function issue.

Comment: @Baskar - have you received the same error?

Comment: Yes it is function portal issue. Just tested. Was able to find the following issue in github. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-table-dotnet-getting-started/issues/5

Comment: Yep, that's the exact same issue... open for about a month and no word from Microsoft :/
I will probably switch to the old storage table...

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateIfNotExists` call requires a reference to `WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable`.  When referenced in a console app, it will replace the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` with the version `1.0.9.1`.  This is not supported by Azure Functions at this point.  Kindly raise an issue with CosmosDB team on this issue.  We have an issue tracking this at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2026#issuecomment-343910660

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and for the reference.
I wish I would have seen it sooner, could have saved a couple of hours.
Microsoft should stop promoting the premium storage over at the portal knowing it's not working as it should.